# Building mysql-5.5.19 from source on ubuntu 11.10 with the static flag

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

```
[ 99%] Building CXX object sql/CMakeFiles/sql.dir/sql_builtin.cc.o
Linking CXX static library libsql.a
[100%] Built target sql
[100%] Building CXX object sql/CMakeFiles/mysqld.dir/main.cc.o
Linking CXX executable mysqld
c++: error: _ALL_STATIC=1: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [sql/mysqld] Error 1
make[1]: *** [sql/CMakeFiles/mysqld.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

`./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mysql --with-mysqld-user=mysql --without-debug --with-client-ldflags=-all-static --with-mysqld-ldflags=-all-static --disable-shared --localstatedir=/usr/local/mysql/data --with-extra-charsets=none --enable-assembler --with-unix-socket-path=/tmp/mysql.socket`

Those are my build flags. I have installed build essentials. I am really unsure what the problem is. Theres not much of a error.

Answer (score 0):

```
c++: error: _ALL_STATIC=1: No such file or directory
```

Thats the error right there, and its being caused by your

```
--with-client-ldflags=-all-static --with-mysqld-ldflags=-all-static
```

Perhaps you meant -static , not -all-static ?

Its worth noting that MySQL 5.5 has a cmake only build system, so you're probably better off porting all of those to the appropriate cmake build flags.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/source-configuration-options.html

Its also worth nothing that 5.5 has landed in precise, and will be the only version of MySQL in 12.04, so you could backport those packages to 11.10 if you were so inclined.